# Why 'handlePost' is not defined?

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, relayjs, relay

Try to add a handler to my Node, React button component, to insert a row in DB, but I got an error, though I am just copying code from an example tutorial. What is wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `handlePost` is not defined in `class Button`. But you are specifying it as `this.handlePost`. Move the method inside `class Button`.